# Toolbar onBackPressed

Tags: android

I have a camera preview on my class. 
When I click back button, it return to mainClass. If I click on the camera preview button it go back to camera preview and works ok.

When I click the Toolbar back button it return to mainClass. if i click on the camera preview button it shows this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 10:33:00.271 1916-1916/org.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     Process: org.example.ricardo.tcc2, PID: 1916
03-16 10:33:00.271 1916-1916/org.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)' on a null object reference
```

MainClass -> previewClass -> backPressed -> MainClass -> previewClass = ok

MainClass -> previewClass -> toolbarBack -> MainClass -> previewClass = error

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. This will make finish the current activity and move back to previous activity on toolbar back button press

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        .......................
   }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```